# Auto update primary key after deleting information

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, primary-key

Anyone know how to solve this ID problem?

For example :

```
ID | Message
1  |  Hi
2  |  Philemon
3  |  Car              <-- Delete this row
4  |  Tay
5  |  Bye
```

When you delete the 3rd row, the ID after the row will auto update and fill in the ID.

```
ID  | Message
1   | Hi
2   | Philemon
3   | Tay
4   | Bye
```

More information :

```
private void btnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
        {
            int ID = Int32.Parse(lblID.Text);
            var DeleteSh = (from delsh in Setupctx.shifthours
                            where delsh.idShiftHours == ID
                            select delsh).Single();
            Setupctx.DeleteObject(DeleteSh);
            Setupctx.SaveChanges();
            txtStart.Text = "";
            txtStop.Text = "";
            this.Edit_Shift_Hours_Load(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            MessageBox.Show("Selected Shift Timing Has Been Deleted.");
        }
    }
```

This is the code to delete the row. After deleting it, I need the ID to auto-update so that it will fill the deleted ID with the next data. Currently I'm able to delete the information but the ID remains the same.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: Could you get the table create script and paste here?

Comment: Do you have a trigger that's doing that?

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,287156,287203#msg-287203

Comment: If your question is "How do I do this," and the ID is a Primary Key for the table, the answer is "don't."  Once Primary Keys are generated, *they should never be reused.*

Comment: You don't have an id problem, just delete the row. If the id is meant to be a primary key, who cares what number it actually represents. It's just supposed to maintain uniqueness across records.

Answer (score 6):

Do **not** do this, suppose someone links to your page, http://mysite.com/article.aspx?ArticleID=1234, and you delete some index before it, all of a sudden 1234 references something entirely different.  Not to mention all the foreign key constraints that have to be updated (implying your database is normalized properly).

It would be a concurrency and usability nightmare.

Comment: Just thinking about it makes me shudder. We have databases with hundred thousands of lines and even millions in some. What a waste of processing power (and effort) that would be !!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to do this would be to first delete the item in question, then select the items in the table, drop the table and then create it again inserting the table data again afterwards.

This would only be possible if you have no foreign keys linked in your db as you would get a reference error otherwise.

Other than this.. Just don't do it.

If you really need a column with consecutive ID's add another column that is not the primary key column that you can update without breaking relationships to other tables. But then again, you wont be able to reference it from other tables